# How can I get the path to a file?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to get the path of a any kind of file but in don't know why it only works with images, with any other file extension path is always null. Here's my code:

```
private string GetPath(Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
        string path;
        string[] projection = new[] { Android.Provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns.Data };
        using (ICursor cursor = ManagedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null))
        {
            if (cursor != null)
            {
                int columnIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(Android.Provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns.Data);
                cursor.MoveToFirst();
                path = cursor.GetString(columnIndex);                    
            }
        }
        return path;
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there any other way to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Uri has a function getPath() which is called like this:

```
uri.getPath()
```

You can probably cast that to a string.

As suggested by this post:

[Convert file: Uri to File in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975197/convert-file-uri-to-file-in-android)

EDIT

In Xamarin this function doesn't exist.

According to this post it should be quite easy:

[Android File Path (Xamarin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309080/android-file-path-xamarin)

It uses the official docs of Xamarin:

http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/pick_image/

Comment: Thanks for your answers :) But I was wondering if is there any way to do a generic function for all file extensions, not only with specific types (Android.Provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data only works for audio files, and Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data  with image files)

Comment: If you want to get all the files i suggest this page: http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/files/browse_files/

this will list every file in a specific directory.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this genius ryupold, there is a solution

https://gist.github.com/ryupold/fe38e5acbe1586681e27